# Should Stack Overflow remove the regex tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

***Due to a complete rewrite by 10 people, I am restoring MY original question which was decimated.***

---

Based on the visceral responses to 3 questions I posed in the last 3 days,
I've drawn the conclusion that Stack Overflow appear to reject Regex questions.
And has a designated user to decide those rejections.

The responses to my legitimate questions are both visceral and unprofessional !!

I don't plan to ask these questions again, and you are good at burying questions. And I understand that. You've been nothing but harsh to me, which is not ok at all.

I am an expert on Regex and I don't see a defense of this overly duplicate marking behavior.

---

This part is from an editor who managed to link my other questions which
were all posted in sucsesion after each were serially deleted.

For reference, the questions were:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390467/why-is-every-other-question-with-the-regex-tag-marked-as-duplicate
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390609/why-is-every-other-question-with-the-regex-tag-marked-as-duplicate
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390626/why-is-every-third-regex-question-marked-as-a-duplicate

---

It was a simple question really:

**Why is every other question with the REGEX tag marked as DUPLICATE?**

Then by popular demand, I went on to make a list of this provable behavior.

Comment: We're throwing out the baby with the bathwater here, no?

Comment: This is my last time on SO. I wish I could have helped a lot, but it doesn't look like that expertise is needed here. Have a nice life.

Comment: You may be being a bit rash in leaving, but your decision is yours alone, of course.

Comment: for easier reference deleted posts: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390467/why-is-every-other-question-with-the-regex-tag-marked-as-duplicate and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390609/why-is-every-other-question-with-the-regex-tag-marked-as-duplicate and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390626/why-is-every-third-regex-question-marked-as-a-duplicate

Comment: No we don't reject it. eg, [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970?tab=topactivity) earned 100K+ rep in 1 year with regex as his major

Comment: @SagarV and it was not so long ago. I didn't want to single out Wiktor in my answer but "vigilant user" was written with him in mind.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yup. He earned 100K+ in 2018-2019

Comment: Don't remove the regex tag. Some people use it to avoid seeing regex tagged questions.

Comment: I have very often have had questions about regex, and not a single time was the content of an existing question (that generally were duplicates) not applicable to my problem. I question your assertion. Duplicates help solve regex problems.

Comment: From my limited time here and what I've observed, it seems beginners use the regex questions to practice and hone their skills. It would seem to me that given the existing regex pool of questions asked and answered there can be no real benefit of searches in this category. This is not due to technique, but to the complete and utter dilution and blurred outcome of that realization. I suggest you let them completely take over the tag for that purpose.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - Duplicate is a word that doesn't apply to regex. I'm an expert and that's my opinion. Maybe you have questions.

Answer (score 30):

Over the past 30 days, about 30% of regex questions were closed, and nearly 80% were answered. So at a glance it appears we're [beating Sturgeon's Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) by a fair margin; that's not too shabby for a topic that cross-cuts so many other areas of expertise.

Looks to me like Regex is alive and well!

Comment: Appears _`closed`_ is the keyword here. Marked duplicates are closed, out of the search stream. So are ones on hold.  Difference is _hold_ requires a consensus of 5 votes. Where as duplicates are a one man show.

Answer (score 16):

You may be a regex expert, but you are a few years late registering on the site if you want to answer a lot of "new" regex questions. I remember that when I started answering here, I wasn't even aware of the concept of duplicate. That's normal. You learned that concept the hard way, I'm sorry for you.

It seems that a lot of regex questions have been answered already by other experts on the site. So a lot of regex questions are duplicate and that will be more and more true.

Some vigilant users try to be very quick at closing the questions if they're duplicate, just to avoid extra noise of same questions & answers again. Sometimes they're wrong. You can ping them if you think they are (use their full name, see [how comment replies work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)) but you better have good arguments. If your arguments are convincing, other users may follow you and help you reopen the question.

Just like python questions, C questions, Java questions, like high-traffic tag questions when the technology is well established.

I suggest that you:

- pick the [best regex questions (score > 500)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D%20score%3A500&mixed=0), see the answers and try to add something new if you can
- try to find some [unanswered regex questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3A0&mixed=0)
- try to find some questions about relatively "new" parts of regex
- specialize in some language tags (all languages have subtle differences when it comes to regex (for instance see [Python 3.7.4: 're.error: bad escape \s at position 0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328587/python-3-7-4-re-error-bad-escape-s-at-position-0), a python 3.7 regex question, that doesn't apply to python 3.6 - disclaimer: I answered that one, along with 12 others in 2019 where I got at least 1 upvote. Note that I'm *not* a regex expert. Also note that some of them where closed as duplicates after I answered :))
- check if a duplicate exists before answering a regex question that looks easy to you,

There's still room for answering questions that won't be closed as duplicate in the regex tag.

Comment: Your answer is loaded with hints for a successful experience finding just the right algorithm for what you need. Regex inherently is not language dependent. It is an art that custom crafts a solution to search and manipulate text. Solutions cant be collected and used as a menu to order pies. It can't be pigeon holed and reused. I've looked at almost all of the regex solutions on StackOverflow submitted within the last 10 years. Every single one of them take the wrong approach. It's a game of ignorance. Wile you think your giving me advice, I assure you, you're not.

Comment: "I've looked at almost all of the regex solutions on StackOverflow submitted within the last 10 years": there are 400k+ answers. You've been there _a month_. Sorry it's not just possible. You appear like you know everything on regex. If the solutions are wrong, then write your own ones. There are 200k open regex questions, so adding a proper answer on each one and getting one vote gets you 2 million rep. I don't see the problem then

Comment: @x15 You claim, *"It is an art that custom crafts a solution to search and manipulate text. Solutions cant be collected and used as a menu to order pies. It can't be pigeon holed and reused."* If that's truly the case, then regex questions would indeed be off-topic for Stack Overflow. This isn't a "give me teh codez" site; we don't write custom, one-off solutions for everyone. Rather, this is like an encyclopedia or wiki, where we are developing a library of high-quality answers to commonly-asked programming questions. If there's nothing general or reusable in regex answers, that's very sad.

Comment: "Write a regex for me" questions are very likely to be closed. That is how it should be. That's not the purpose of this site. What are *not* closed are general, reference-style questions about regular expressions, and those still merit the [regex] tag.

Comment: I think that about sums it up fella's _200k open regex questions_, whatever open means, that are all reference quality, _waiting to be answered by an expert_, me, _to construct a library of high-quality answers_. Trouble is, that version is not the way _Regex_ works, never has and never will. The duplicates pointed to are low quality and plain and extremely outdated. Good luck with that business model _!_

Comment: I don't agree with the suggestion to go and post late answers on the best questions with score > 500. Too many users don't have the good enough judgement about whether they are contributing something new/useful here. You can see a majority of late answers on highly scored questions are 1. just adding to the tail of crap, or 2. duplicating content because the answerer didn't bother to review existing answers first

Comment: @wim and I personally never do that. But if a super-expert discovers stackoverflow, they may add something new. Else, moderators are here to delete duplicates/low quality answers.